# ESLint - "no-unused-vars" warning for every import

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'm using an Angular project and just wanted to use ESLint with Prettier again. Sadly there is an annoying problem that every import is shown with the warning `'XYZ' is defined but never used. eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars)`

[image]

[image]

I can only fix this if I completly disable this rule. But then I wouldn't get a hint for unused const variables like in line 22.

My eslintrc.json:

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser", // Specifies the ESLint parser
  "extends": [
    "plugin:angular/johnpapa", //ESLint rules for your angular project with checks for best-practices, conventions or potential errors.
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", // Uses the recommended rules from the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
    "prettier", // Uses eslint-config-prettier to disable ESLint rules from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin that would conflict with prettier
    "plugin:prettier/recommended" // Enables eslint-plugin-prettier and eslint-config-prettier. This will display prettier errors as ESLint errors. Make sure this is always the last configuration in the extends array.
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
    "sourceType": "module" // Allows for the use of imports
  },
  "settings": {
    "angular": {
      "version": "detect" // Tells eslint-plugin-react to automatically detect the version of React to use
    }
  },
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "rules": {
    // Place to specify ESLint rules. Can be used to overwrite rules specified from the extended configs
    "no-empty-function": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": ["off"],
  },
  "ignorePatterns": ["/*.*"]
}
```

Used dependencies:

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.4",
"eslint": "^7.31.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-angular": "^4.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
"prettier": "^2.3.2",
"prettier-eslint": "^12.0.0",
```

Comment: __Looks like your using VSCode, try using `"typescript.format.enable": false` in your `".vscode/settings.json"` file.__

Comment: @JAY-DEV I've added it to the settings.json in `%appdata%\Code\User` as new line not nested in [typescript] and it didn't affected anything.

Comment: If you want to keep the rule, then remove all unused variables. Why would you want to keep them cluttering your code anyway?

Comment: @funkizer you can obviously see that I need Router, TranslateService etc. If I remove this imports the whole file is broken. These warning are just wrong. Completly wrong. The imports are used.

Comment: Anybody with an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there was a problem between some versions and also one package missing. The package `"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.19.0"`.

It works now with the following packages in the `devDependencies`:

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.19.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.19.0",
"eslint": "^7.23.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
"eslint-plugin-angular": "^4.0.1",
"prettier": "^2.3.2",
"prettier-eslint": "^12.0.0"
```

Before this the versions were even newer for the eslint packages:

```
"eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-angular": "^4.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0"
```

So I used the npm command `npm update --save-dev` to update all dev dependencies which downgraded the listed ones and made it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `import type { TranslateService } from "..."` to precise this only going to be used for typing and not an actual variable in your code.